# Crop part of a page

Tags: jquery, css

For the purpose of taking a screenshot I want to isolate a specific part/element of a page (specified using a CSS selector).

How can I do that?

I am thinking this might be possible by wrapping the page into a  or into an IFrame but do not know how to proceed.

I would like to avoid reloading the page.

**edit:**
I actually solved this using another way - I crop out the part using PHP after obtaining the element coordinates in Javascript: https://gist.github.com/amenk/11208415

Comment: isolate as in darken the rest of the page? If that is the case: With JavaScript duplicate the element, set the height/width of the copy to be the same, and set position absolute, placing it exactly on top. Then add an overlay div under the copy. It shouldn't be too hard actually.

Comment: Isolate as displaying only that part in the top left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JSFIDDLE WORKING -NO IE-

http://jsfiddle.net/8Rx34/ :
use it with id in page, in this test case "box1" or "box2" or "box3" or "box4" or "box5"

tested a bit seems ok.
Idea it's to get an element ID and apply `myScreenshot` class.

Code of myScreenshot css:

```
.myScreenshot {
 position: absolute;
 left:0px;
 top: 0px;
}
```

Then copy the selected dom element (with his childrens) just as first element of body.

```
$('body').prepend($('#myIdElementToCrop'));
```

After
    body>*{
      display: none;
    }

```
.myScreenshot:first-child{
  display: initial !important;
}
```

to let all work properly, all have to start as hidden element in css and with js the width of the element must be catched to apply it to copy of the element so right width will be everytime displayed.

```
$(function() {
     var idOfDom = prompt("Insert ID of DOMElement to apply myScreenshot");
     if ($('#'+idOfDom).length > 0){
         var actualWidth = $('#'+idOfDom).width();
        $('body').prepend($('#'+idOfDom));
        $('#'+idOfDom).addClass("myScreenshot").css('width',actualWidth);
        $('body>*').css('display', 'none').css('visibility','visible');
     }
});
```